# Nested lists within YAML outputted iteratively with ERB in Middleman

Tags: nested, erb, middleman, middleman-4

I want to be able to have an indeterminate amount of lists in my YAML file and if there are any defined to then loop through them iteratively in the template file outputting their contents.

I'm currently using the following YAML format;

```
:list
  :has_list: true
  :list_tables:
    :list_table_1
      -  name: list name
      -  data: data name
```

I'm currently using the following template code;

```
<% if entry[:list][:has_list] %>
    <% entry[:list][:list_tables].each do |l| %>
        <%= l.name %>
        <%= l.data %>
    <% end %>
<% end>
```

but I'm getting blanks where the data should be. It's outputting as true because if I put in an else block and play around I can see that particular part of the logic is working. It's just where it has to finally output the table data. I think I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what. It's not erroring out which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Is your yaml valid? It didn't pass for me at http://www.yamllint.com/ or 
http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator.

I changed it to the following which made it validate

`list: 
  has_list: true
  list_tables: 
    - list_table_1: 
        - name: "list name"
        - data: "data name"
    - list_table_2: 
        - name: "list name"
        - data: "data name"`